# Angular blur validation preventing submission of separate form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have an Angular page with a form for adding people, and a button (outside this form) to submit the list of people.

When the user focuses on a text input in the form, and then clicks to submit the list, the validation error from the text input appears but the submit event never occurs.

An example of this issue here: http://plnkr.co/edit/6Z0UUs

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
  <form name="form1" novalidate="">
    <input type="text" name="field1" ng-model="vm.name" required>
    <div ng-messages="form1.field1.$error" ng-if="form1.field1.$touched">
      <label ng-message="required">Name is required</label>
    </div>
    <!-- 
    This form adds a person to a list. I've not included this code to keep the example simple 
    <input type="submit" value="Add person"> 
    -->
  </form>
  <button ng-click="vm.submit()">Submit list</button>
</div>
```

-

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('MyCtrl', function() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.name = '';

    vm.submit = function () {
        alert('submitted');    
    };
});
```

To replicate:

1. Click on the text input but leave blank
2. Click submit

Current behavior: "Name is required" appears thanks to the validation. Clicking 'Submit' again displays the 'submitted' alert.

Expected behavior: "Name is required" appears thanks to the validation *and* the 'submitted' alert appears.

Desired behavior: The 'submitted' alert appears and I add some code to vm.submit() to hide the 'Name is required' validation message as it's not important when the list is submitted.

I've observed that removing the `ng-messages` block fixes the issue, but I do need to show a validation message. Using a more basic directive (`ng-show`) to show the validation message instead does not help.

Any insights into what I'm doing wrong, or workarounds to achieve my desired behavior, would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Modified Answer] : 
Here is a working plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/JCyRi8xp4L3FtafABblS?p=preview

```
vm.preventDefaultIfSubmitted = function($event){
if($event.relatedTarget.id == "submit"){
    $event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
};
```

The idea is to get the $event when the blur occurs and then to look at the id of the relatedTarget (which is your button in this case) and if it is then you cancel the $event, otherwise you keep it.

That way if you click anywhere your validation message appears and if you click on submit it doesnt

Comment: It's a 2-step process. The form is for adding a person to a list which is shown on the page (I've hidden the rest of that form, including the 'Add' button, to simplify the Plunkr). The button is for then submitting that list. It's actually desirable for the add-person-form to be empty when submitting the list, but the person name is required when adding to the list.

Comment: Oh ok, I do understand what the problem is now.  One idea would be to stop the default event when you blur from the input but you'll lose the message everytime you blur out of the field ... But it could keep the validation message for when you press add.

Comment: I'd say your problem is the ng-if in your message because even if you enter a name you've got you validation message opening

Comment: The issue isn't that the validation message appears, but that it prevents the call to submit() from happening

Comment: I'm liking the look of your modified answer. Currently the validation message never displays.. will see if I can tweak :)

Comment: Fantastic - this works! The reason I didn't initially see the validation message was that the submit button was touching the input, and I must have mouseovered the submit button when leaving the input (so it became the relatedTarget). Moving the submit button, and changing `$event.relatedTarget.id == "submit"` to `$event.relatedTarget && $event.relatedTarget.id === "submit"` fixes the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

May this help for form validation

```
<form role="form" name="projectBriefFrm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="project_title">Project Title
                            <sup>*</sup>
                        </label>
                        <input ng-model="project.title" ng-required="true" type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Untitled Project"
                        />
                        <div class="row">
                            <span class="errorMessage" ng-show="!isProjectModelValid && projectBriefFrm.title.$invalid">Please provide title</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container" id="editor-title">
                            <label for="project_brief">Project Brief
                                <sup>*</sup>
                            </label>
                            <div class="row" id="editor">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 nopadding">
                                    <textarea ng-model="project.brief" name="brief" cult-editor ng-required="true"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <span class="errorMessage" ng-show="!isProjectModelValid && projectBriefFrm.brief.$invalid">Please provide project brief</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Not sure how this is meant to help - doesn't seem to tackle the specific issue I'm having. I have no issues with getting validation to work in normal circumstances...